# Windows Forms assembly

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-assembly, disassembly, decompiling

Somehow Visual Studio deleted my files, so for now I have empty c# form. But, when I press F5 (of course here is a mistake) but Studio suggests me to open the last assembly. And it works!
The question is:
Can I decompile this assembly (somehow) and get the source code?

Comment: You probably clicked "Ignore and continue" on [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ3gJ.png), which appears when there is a compilation issue with the designer class. Use something like JetBrains' DotPeek or Redgate's .NET Reflector. You'll probably need to rename the controls back to what you had, but it should work. In future use something like Git should prevent these kind of mistakes. Even a local repository should help, or Github offers free private repositories, as Bitbucket does, etc.

Comment: how do you know? I have this message, yep
wait a sec

Comment: Update: in testing this, my faulty code is still present in Form1.Designer.cs. Can you check your form's designer file and see if your UI code is all still there? If it is, fix the compile errors and you might be OK.

Comment: I can add fiull project on google disk, if you wanna see

Comment: form designer have all names of my buttons, labels etc like this:
 this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 225);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 92);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 7;
            this.button1.Text = "code";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

Comment: I had a mistake like John's, but this pop-up message is no longer in project, earlier there was the exact mistake-message.

Comment: Sorry, I had to do other things. If you try and rebuild your project, do you get compile errors in the designer? If you do, fix them. It might fix your project.